# ¿como puedo hallar la longitud de la lista de insectos con estos hechos?

Tags: prolog

```
animal('conejo').
animal('venado').
animal('león').
animal('zorro').
animal('gato').
animal('camaleón').
animal('halcón).
animal('mosca').
animal('perro').
animal('cocodrilo').
animal('mosquito').
animal('serpiente').
animal('cotorra').
animal('gallina').
come('león', 'venado').
come('halcón', 'conejo').
come('camaleón', 'mosca').
come('zorro', 'gallina').
grupo('mamífero', ['gato', 'perro','conejo','venado','zorro','león']).
grupo('reptil', ['camaleón','cocodrilo','serpiente']).
grupo('insecto', ['mosca','mosquito']).
grupo('ave', ['halcón','cotorra','gallina']).
depredador(X):- animal(X), come(X,_),!.
presa(X):- animal(X), come(_,X),!.
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del predicado [length/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2) sobre la lista que te interesa obtener la longitud. Por ejemplo:

```
grupo('insecto', ListaInsectos), 
length(ListaInsectos, Longitud), 
writeln(Longitud)
```

Salida:

```
2
ListaInsectos = [mosca, mosquito],
Longitud = 2
```